# send mail code not work for java EE 5 web project

Tags: java, email, java-ee-5

I am using myeclipse 7, where i have added java EE 5 libraries witch i required.If i add the mail.jar externally to the application, it calling the javaee.jar from java EE 5 libraries.It's not using the mail.jar.If i remove java EE 5 libraries then it is working, But i require java EE 5 libraries. How can i send mail using javaee.jar of java EE 5 library?.

If it require below is my hava code for sed mail

```
 String  d_email = "email@gmail.com",
                d_password = "pass",
                d_host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                d_port  = "465",
                m_to = "email@gmail.com",
                m_subject = "Testing",
                m_text = "This is the testing email.";

        public Main()
        {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", d_host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", d_port);
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", d_port);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

            SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();

            try
            {
                Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
                Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
                session.setDebug(true);

                MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                msg.setText(m_text);
                msg.setSubject(m_subject);
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email));
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(m_to));
                Transport.send(msg);

                System.out.println("Mail Sent");
            }
            catch (Exception mex)
            {
                mex.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main blah = new Main();
    }

    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator
    {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(d_email, d_password);
        }
    }
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/LineInputStream
    at javax.mail.Session.loadProvidersFromStream(Session.java:928)
    at javax.mail.Session.access$000(Session.java:174)
    at javax.mail.Session$1.load(Session.java:870)
    at javax.mail.Session.loadResource(Session.java:1084)
    at javax.mail.Session.loadProviders(Session.java:889)
    at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:210)
    at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:232)
    at com.ctn.origin.connection.Main.<init>(Main.java:35)
    at com.ctn.origin.connection.Main.main(Main.java:55)
```

Comment: In what way it doesn't work? Does it give you compilation errors, runtime exceptions, doesn't produce expected results?

Comment: its gives run time error i adit my question describing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** manually add container specific libraries like `javaee.jar` to your project. It would only lead to runtime troubles if you deploy and run the project on a container of a different make/version. The `javaee.jar` is specific to Glassfish. Since Glassfish by itself already ships with a `mail.jar` this suggests that your target runtime is not Glassfish at all. It's probably Tomcat or JBoss or something.

If you did this to overcome project compilation errors, you should have solved this differently. I don't do MyEclipse, but I believe this is much similar to Eclipse, so this Eclipse based answer should work out for MyEclipse as well: rightclick the project, choose *Properties*, go to *Target Runtime* section and select the target runtime (the servletcontainer which you'd like to use) from the list. This way Eclipse will automatically include its libraries in the project's build path the right way.

#### See also:

- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/)